# Trim an input text and a textarea (two ids)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea, trim

The question is simple, i want to trim an input text (with id title)and a textarea (with id description), how can i do? I only know how todo to the title id, but not both:

```
if (!$.trim($("#title)".val()))
```

Comment: The trim function only operates on an input string. You'll still need to extract your two elements and execute the trim on each one separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if both have to be empty

```
if ( !$.trim($("#title").val()) && !$.trim($("#description").val()) )
```

If just one empty is wrong, use

```
if ( !$.trim($("#title").val()) || !$.trim($("#description").val()) )
```

Comment: Thanks mpungjan for the modification, but this doesn't work, only work if i doesn't write any input, but if i write any of the two inputs this doesn't work...

Comment: I did not create the script, just fixed the brackets. Change && to || to make it work if he enters only one or neither